# How can i click components behind modal when modal is opening in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to do this layout: [image]

Currently I do the layout by this way:

- menu is belong to the below part and i marginTop: -30 for it to above the image
- FlatList is absolute view and have zIndex bigger than Menu. FlatList have dynamic data and each item of FlatList have textInput to search data ( look at this pic ) 
  [image]
  I have tried 2 ways:
  **First way:**
- I used  for the list filtered data, it is limited by the Flatlist area so that my filtered list cannot display fully, just 2 rows visible, the rest of filtered data is invisible. I have tried increase the height of the Flatlist and now I can see the filtered list fully but I cannot click the menu button because menu is overived by the Flatlist,
  **Second way**
- I use Modal and tried with this library: react-native-modal-dropdown, I can reach my expertation UI but because it use Modal so when Modal is appearing, my textInput in Item is loss focus, so that I cannot continually input to TextInput until I close the Modal. 
  Do you guys have any solution for it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The modal component use the native Modal, you won't be able to interact with elements outside it while it is still visible.
I am not sure to understand why you cannot use View to display the results, but maybe you could try with FlatList ?

Comment: i have updated my question, thanks for your support

Comment: If you know in advance the height of the green element, you could try the 1st solution, using flatlist inside the blue view, with a common parent view for the green and red element, an absolute positionning and a top: HeightOfGreenView + PaddingBellow

Comment: could you please explain more detail, i am not sure i understand correctly your idea. Currently the blue is still the parent of the green and red, but as i told in the question, the red will be limit its' height in the blue so the red cannot show fully as I want. If I increase the height of the blue to show the red fully, it will override the Menu so I cannot click the buttons in menu.